# API Gateway URL (endpoint id) Changed after “sls deploy” and endpoint is not appearing in API Gateway

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, python-3.6, aws-api-gateway, serverless-framework

I recently added changes to my python lambda function and tried to redeploy to production using

`sls deploy --stage prod`

The endpoint appears and the deployment was successful. However, I noticed that the endpoint id changed.

example:

from : https://111222333444.execute-api.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/prod/forecast

to: https://333555777888.execute-api.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/prod/forecast

This is weird since I’ve already done multiple deployments using serverless framework and it never changed the endpoint id before. Another problem is I can’t use the new one created since it does not appear in API Gateway, CloudFormation and even in S3. However, in my serverless cli it said that it was successfully deployed under the same:

• service

• stage

• region

• stack

• resources

The only change I’ve done besides changing that one line of code was I deleted a cron event associated with this endpoint but I strongly feel it shouldn’t have affected this.

Any lead would surely be appreciated. Thank you so much!

P.S Im using the ff: 
frameworkVersion: 2 
runtime environment: python3.6

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Isn't it accidentally deployed to another AWS account?

You can check arn of resources in sls logs(add `-v` if you dont see logs in detail) and check if that lambda exists in proper account. Arn has aws account id which is really usable to track where you deployed.

Comment: Thank you so much @prosunshining! I was able to solve this yesterday and was about to post the solution but I appreciate that you already came up with the same solution. I added a -v flag to check the logs and it seems like I was using the wrong access key and secret key. I simply used: 

`aws configure` and added the correct credentials. However, my CloudFormation stack was still drifted due to the changes made before hand and I have little to no experience fixing these despite the available documentations. May I ask if you already done this before? Thank you so much.

Comment: @FaitAccompli Yes, I had the same issue several times before, and even these days too ;)

Comment: How did you remove the CloudFormation drifts, may I ask? @prosunshine

Comment: I use `sls remove` as first option if you meant to delete cloudformation stack created by serverless framework.

Comment: Wouldn't that remove resources that were already made? After removing, I assume you redeploy it again right? Would the endpoint id change?

Comment: endpoint id will change if you redeploy after `sls remove`, even under the same aws account

Comment: Got it, thank you so much. I hope serverless will have a workaround for this soon since it's kinda troublesome to change endpoint urls when it encounters these problems.